# Any help to solve these C# NEST (ElasticSearch) errors?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Recently, I have started to work on C# NEST (ElasticSearch), and having some problems:

1. Error Message: **No route taking 1 parameters {index}/_doc/{id}**
   when using
   `await ESClient.GetAsync(DocumentPath<TModel>.Id(new Id(model.Id)), x => x.Index(indexName));`
   or
   `await ESClient.DocumentExistsAsync(DocumentPath<TModel>.Id(new Id(model.Id)), x => x.Index(indexName))`
2. Error Message: **Invalid NEST response built from a successful (200) low level call on POST: /{index}/_bulk**
   when using
   `await ESClient.IndexManyAsync(list, indexName)`
   or
   `await ESClient.BulkAsync(x => x.Index(indexName).IndexMany(list))`
   whereas this works fine
   `await ESClient.IndexDocumentAsync(model)`

With my respect.

Comment: Are you using the same ES client version as your server? I.e., if your server is running ElasticSearch v6, then you *have* to use the ES/NEST client v6.

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary , (2) solved:
I am using ElasticSearch 8.3.2 and NEST 7.17.4.
The workaround solution is enabling the compatibility mode:
`var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(str)).EnableApiVersioningHeader();`  
[source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.17/connecting-to-elasticsearch-v8.html#enabling-compatibility-mode)