# ElasticsearchClient - exception when creating new document with CreateAsync()

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-client

I use ElasticsearchClient for .NET from **Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch 8.9.3** library.
Trying to create a new document with the following code:

```
var createRequest = new CreateRequest<MyModelDto>("myindex", Id.From(dto))
{
    Document = dto
};
await _client.CreateAsync(createRequest);
```

But it results to the following exception:

> System.Exception: No route taking 1 parameters{index}/*create/{id}
>
> at Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.Requests.ApiUrls.Resolve(RouteValues
> routeValues, IElasticsearchClientSettings settings) in
> /*/src/Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch/Core/Request/ApiUrls.cs:line 68
> at
> Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.Requests.Request.ResolveUrl(RouteValues
> routeValues, IElasticsearchClientSettings settings) in
> /*/src/Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch/Core/Request/Request.cs:line 52
>
> at
> Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.Requests.Request.GetUrl(IElasticsearchClientSettings
> settings) in
> /*/src/Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch/Core/Request/Request.cs:line 56
> at
> Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.PrepareRequest[TRequest,TRequestParameters](TRequest
> request, Action`1 forceConfiguration) in /_/src/Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch/Client/ElasticsearchClient.cs:line 279    at Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.DoRequestAsync[TRequest,TResponse,TRequestParameters](TRequest request, Action`1 forceConfiguration, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) in
> /*/src/Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch/Client/ElasticsearchClient.cs:line 221    at
> Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.DoRequestAsync[TRequest,TResponse,TRequestParameters](TRequest
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
> /*/src/Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch/Client/ElasticsearchClient.cs:line 179    at
> Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.CreateAsync[TDocument](CreateRequest`1
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
> /_/src/Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch/_Generated/Client/ElasticsearchClient.g.cs:line
> 483

What is wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: What server version are you running?

Comment: elasticsearch:8.2.2. This is locally on my machine in Docker.

Comment: You should use a client library that has the same version as your server

Comment: Upgraded elastic server to 8.10.2 but it didn't help, I got the same error. (and I didn't find the image for 8.9.3 version)

Comment: it looks a lot like [this issue](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/473) but it seems to have been solved... maybe this [older thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73141405/any-help-to-solve-these-c-sharp-nest-elasticsearch-errors#comment129178714_73141405) provides a workaround.